# Microsoft Access Database, Insert, Update and Delete in Visual Studio with C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, ms-access-2010, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert a row to a table in Microsoft Access Database via Visual Studio 2015 an c#.

the Scenario is: a class called: `QuestionData` and a class `Question`. A table `exams`, and table `questions`.

my code is:

```
public static bool addQuestion(QuestionData quesData)
    {
        if (quesData == null || quesData.question == null) { return false; }
        List<QuestionData> questionsData = new List<QuestionData>();

        string connetionString = null;
        OleDbConnection cnn;
        connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=database.mdb;";
        cnn = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
        try
        {
            string insertCmd = "INSERT INTO questions (exam_id, [name], question_text, withImage, question_correctAnswer, answer_1, answer_2, answer_3, answer_4) VALUES (@exam_id, @name, @question_text, @withImage, @question_correctAnswer, @answer_1, @answer_2, @answer_3, @answer_4)";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(insertCmd);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@exam_id", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = quesData.examId;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = quesData.question.getName();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@questionText", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = quesData.question.getQuestionText();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@withImage", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = quesData.question.isImageEnabled();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@question_CorrectAnswer", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = quesData.question.getCorrectAnswer();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@answer_1", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = quesData.question.getAnswer(0);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@answer_2", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = quesData.question.getAnswer(1);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@answer_3", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = quesData.question.getAnswer(2);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@answer_4", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = quesData.question.getAnswer(3);

            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            cnn.Open();
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnn.Close();

            return true;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception: \n Source: " + ex.Source + "\n Message: " + ex.Message);
            cnn.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine, with no compiling or run-time errors, and `cmd.ExcuteNonQuery();` line returns positive value `(1)`, but nothing happens to database file. but `Read Query` works fine and does its job.

I searched google, and tried every single solution on the internet, but no thing changed the result.

I appreciate any help, and any guide to solve the problem.

Comment: change the first part like this string insertCmd = "INSERT INTO questions ([exam_id], [name], [question_text], [withImage], [question_correctAnswer], [answer_1], [answer_2], [answer_3], [answer_4])

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the correct `database.mdb` file?  I suspect  the app is writing to a different file than the one you are checking for changes.  To remove any ambiguity, use a full path in your connection string.

Comment: @sstan I don't think so, cause i am using the same Connection String all over the functions, and it works when selecting ones, and editing the database in debug folder via Access software, do affect on reading in  other functions. so i think it just one database. is there any thing i missed?

Comment: Can't think of anything else.  The fact that `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` returned `1` means that the `insert` definitely worked.  so, whatever the problem is, I don't think it's in your code.

Comment: thanks @sstan i'm searching, and if i found any thing that can help others, i will update the question.

Comment: Unless you have to use access, don't.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uONQaT-nwls

Answer (score 0):

With Access the paramaters should be marked as "?". They don't use a name but the order they are added to the Parameters Collection (a fake name is still needed :-))

Try to replace

```
string insertCmd = "INSERT INTO questions (exam_id, [name], question_text, withImage, question_correctAnswer, answer_1, answer_2, answer_3, answer_4) VALUES (@exam_id, @name, @question_text, @withImage, @question_correctAnswer, @answer_1, @answer_2, @answer_3, @answer_4)";
```

with

```
string insertCmd = "INSERT INTO questions (exam_id, [name], question_text, withImage, question_correctAnswer, answer_1, answer_2, answer_3, answer_4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Check that's you are connecting to the right files by using a fixed path. It could be confusing.

By the way you better have to use the using keyword for the Connection object, you will be sure that it will be properly closed when you go out of the using statement (normal way and exception too). This point is only a good practice, not a source of error in your case.

```
using cnn = new OleDbConnection(connetionString)
{
  cnn.open
  //Query the DB
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. but is there any thing to do with permissions, since when executing it with Access software, it asks for permission every time.

Comment: Okay, let's start the standard database debug process. First try to write and execute your insert query in Access (with test data), then copy this query in your application and try to execute it (with the same test data). When you are good you could adapt the query to be dynamic (first with an old a string concatenate, then with parameters).

Comment: That also didn't worked for visual studio, i did replaces insertCmd with:   INSERT INTO questions ( exam_id, name, question_text, withImage, question_correctAnswer, answer_1, answer_2, answer_3, answer_4 ) VALUES ('1', '2', 'A', '1', '3', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');                                                                        and  commented add parameters block and, still with same result!

Comment: Does it work if you do if you write it in a query (in sql mode, not designer) directely in access ? Are you sure you open the connexion to the right .mdb file ? Because "Data Source=database.mdb" could be very confusing if it is your real connexion string (hope not). I know that Visual Studio is copying .mdb file from project to debug folder on each launch. Using a fixed path out of your project could be an idea if you won't reset your database all the time.

Comment: Thanks, @MarcoGuignard , Yes, it works when writing  it via SQL editor, database is opened via database.mdb file in solution explorer, and I found that querying the table after doing INSERT query, does get the inserted row, but after closing it, the records are lost. I think you are right, I will changing the path to a fixed one as you suggested,